# Intervals in axis labels using plotmath symbols

Tags: r, plotmath

I want to use plotmath symbols in R to add an interval to the X axis of a plot, such as `3<=X<=4`. I know you can do something like:

```
x=1:10
x1=3
x2=4

plot(x, xlab=substitute(a <= X *""~ X <= b, list(a=x1,b=x2)))
```

But I cannot remove the second `X` as it will give me an error. Is this even possible? Or should I do some trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
plot(x, xlab=substitute(a <= ~X <= b, list(a=x1, b=x2)))
```